# Restangular No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: cors, restangular

I'm trying to do the following call with Restangular to a JAX-RS REST service (that is CORs enabled).

```
    var baseUsers = Restangular.all("users");

    $scope.users = '{[]}';

    $scope.users = baseUsers.getList().then(function(result) {
        console.log("Got users", response.status);
    }, function(response) {
        console.log("Failed to find users with status code", response.status);
    });
```

But I keep seeing this error in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://135.60.151.27:9080/app/users. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8383' is therefore not allowed access.
```

From POSTMan I can see the CORs headers in the response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Content-Length →2
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Thu, 03 Jul 2014 14:34:25 GMT
X-Powered-By →Servlet/3.0
```

I thought it might be that the REST OPTIONS call was to problem but that too is returning the same CORs headers.

Answer (score 0):

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` does not mix with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

In [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-requests):

> The string "*" cannot be used for a resource that supports credentials.

When you are allowing the credentials it is extremely insecure to allow any origin. This way any site you visit on the internet can theoretically act on your behalf in your incorrectly configured website without your consent or even without your notice.

So you should include only one host in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` or implement a system that adds hostname from the `Host` request header if it matches a predefined whitelist/regexp.

Comment: Ok I actually decided to add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials cause I thought that would fix the problem. I don't have cookies or credentials so I actually don't need this. So I hit the same issue with Access-Control-Allow-Credentials left out of the header returned